# Getting rid of the three top links (Mail, Contacts, Tasks) in Gmail

Tags: gmail

The Gmail user interface contains the following three top links above the "Compose Mail" button:

- Mail
- Contacts
- Tasks

[image: gmail section above compose button]

I'm always on the Mail tab. I'm not using Tasks and I never go to the Contacts tab.

Is it possible to make the links disappear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt it, since they are not considered labels. However, they are collapsable.
[image]
[image]

There is also a [script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/83718) that moves those links below the labels.

> **Script Summary:** Move gmail's top-left menu (Mail, Contacts, Tasks) under list of folders. Works in Firefox (with Greasemonkey), Chrome and Opera.